# convert titled environments with Pandoc from latex to markdown

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I want to convert my latex documents to markdown which I can use in obsidian. However, when I use pandoc, it transforms a latex environment such as

```
\begin{thm}[Theorem name]
 This is a theorem
\end{thm}
```

into

```
::: thm
** 1** (Theorem name). *This is a theorem*
:::
```

Instead, I would like it to turn into a callout

```
> [!thm] **1** Theorem name 
> *This is a theorem*
```

I hoped I could just find the corresponding readers and writers in pandoc and change them a little bit, but it seems to be written in Haskell and I can barely understand what happens there. Also, I tried to look for some examples of how to customize the reader or writer, and found very few sources, which were not too helpful at the end.

I would appreciate any help with this, either if there is already such a way to do it, or a good place to learn enough about pandoc in order to do it myself (which might be extra helpful, since I might have more such conversion problems in the future).

Comment: you can do that easily in Lua (instead of Haskell) using https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html

Comment: @mb21 I might be able to do it easily with lua, the problem is that for some reason it is way too difficult to just download and install it. For the last couple of hours I have been trying to download lpeg for lua, and just keep getting error messages about lua versions and header files. I think that it would be easier for me to just write it from scratch...

Comment: did you read the link I posted? pandoc ships with a built-in lua interpreter :-)

Comment: @mb21 I know. Since this is my first time using lua or lpeg I wanted to actually download and play with it to understand how it works. Unfortunately, running it through pandoc is the only way I can use it for now